# Text editor for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors

My requirements:

1. Ctrl+Y acts as redo
2. I can launch it from the commandline
3. The text is readable

Almost all editors fail at #1 despite this being the standard redo key in every other program I use (FF, Chrome, Eclipse, Open Office, Gimp, etc.)

The KDE editors fail at #2 and print a bunch of garbage to the screen

scribes is the best at #3, but fails at #1.  jedit is the only program I've found that meets the first two criteria, but is the absolute worst at #3.

Right now I think I'm going to by UltraEdit since it's the only one that passes all three.  I was wondering before I do if there are any free options?

Comment: you can launch it, or run it in command line?

Comment: You can launch anything from the command-line. And what do you mean by KDE editors? kate?

Comment: I prefer gedit but it fails #1. Apparently they're sniffing the same glue as the rest of the devs who make shift-ctrl shortcuts. Why do they think hitting 3 keys is more intuitive than hitting 2?

Comment: Pick any editor at all. Change the "Redo" key combo to CTRL+Y. Profit. Open Source FTW.

Comment: "Almost all editors fail at #1"? Almost all editors can remap keys to whatever you want. I know the great and glorious Vim can do this, I suspect that Emacs can also probably do it, despite its many other shortcomings :-)

Comment: @Evan Plaice: What's *intuitive* (define:intuitive from google : "prompted by a natural tendency") about another random letter? Remember, intuitive roughly means "easily guessed". It is much more "easily guessed" that you need to hold shift to do a reverse operation. CTRL+Y is not intuitive; there is no logical way to guess it.

Comment: @pax It can; as you get used to its keybindings you need to make them more and more difficult to keep your fingers limber

Comment: houbysoft: what i meant was when you launch kate or kwrite from the commandline they spit out all kinds of crap and don't always work perfectly.  i enquired about this and they said that it was not meant to be run from the commandline

Comment: houbysoft: the reason Ctrl+Y is intuitive is that it is the shortcut for redo in every program i've used my entire life.  even on linux most use Ctrl+Y: open office, gimp, firefox, chrome, eclipse, etc.

Comment: If you're having text problems in more than one program, it is very likely that you have a problem with your font paths.

Comment: @Ben: if KWrite and Kate are producing a lot of output, it probably means you have them configured in debug mode or something. When I launch them from the command line they don't print anything (and they work just as well as when launched from KLauncher).

Comment: In Vim, redo is `^r`. What could be more intuitive than that? But the usual method is to use `.`, a single unshifted key so it's also faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give sublime a try. You can get it here:
http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Answer (score 10):

1. There are tons of editors that let you rebind keys, so any of them would work
2. You can launch any program from the command-line
3. Even more editors let you set the font of the displayed text

In short, you should be able to configure most editors to satisfy those requirements

Answer (score 3):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/)

Comment: Nice!  I hadn't seen Geany before but it looks pretty good.  I'm going to try it for awhile too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use vim. Vim easy mode (evim) already uses those commands, and it's free.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you have [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) which is what Notepad++ in Linux is actually based off of. I use it when I don't want to pull out my heavyweight IDE and when CLI tools (Vim, nano) are too light.

Comment: I love scite. YEAH

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it meets all those 3 requirements. I think it does, but either way, you might want to check out [Notepad](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)++.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Last time I've checked, it runs only on Windows.

Comment: True, my apologies for I forgot about that detail, explicit in the title. However, i had heard it was possible to convert it for Linux. I do not know if it works or so, but either way, you could try to run it with something like Wine for Linux, which allows you to run Windows applications in linux. Try checking it out: http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: @Luis Miguel: while possible, it is somewhat unnecessary and unnatural. There are plenty of good editors, almost all of which satisfy the conditions of the asker provided he can learn to configure them properly.

Comment: It runs in wine, but thats a pain in the butt and really slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to give Scribes a try as they were nice enough to patch the Ctrl+Y issue for me.
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mystilleef/scribes/scribes-dev-0.4/revision/570

Answer (score 0):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) is much faster than gedit and is my editor of choice whenever I don't want to use vim.